# Inkscape: joining 2 nodes

Tags: inkscape, path

How to join these 2 nodes and close the path with a straight line? I tried selecting them, but when I press *join nodes* , it doesn't do anything.

[image: 2 nodes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your recent questions on this site you might want to learn how to use the boolean operators in Inkscape. Look at [this youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1nw9Bz86Po) for the basics.

In this case you could create a rectangle and rotate and scale it so that it covers the gap you are trying to fill. Then select both the rectangle and your original path and select **Path>Union** to merge them into one path.

Comment: Yes, that is logical. I thought there is some way with the nodes. What ever I tried,I couldn't connected them in straight path. I have watched several tutorials but I couldn't find correct way.

Answer (score 4):

Only *open* nodes (nodes with at most one outgoing line) can be joined. In your case, the nodes are *closed* (they have two outgoing lines).

[image: Open and closed Nodes]

Even if you could connect the nodes (which would be odd, because they would have three outgoing lines afterwards) the result wouln't be what you want. Consider the difference between a path stroke and a filled path. You work with a filled path.

Comment: How to create single line path out of this path ? So that does not have any thickness.

Comment: Representing a solid object by just a stroke is not possible in general. In your case its possible by drawing the object again *by hand*. The easiest solution to your actual problem was described by filip: Create a rectangle, rotate it, lay it over the part you want to connect, and union rectangle and the object.

Comment: Not as a path effect, but as an extension which takes a solid object and (tries to) transform that to a stroke, yes. However (as already pointed out), a meaningfull transformation is not always possible. How would you transform a disk into a stroke?

Comment: I don't know. For some simpler paths I would say: for every 2 neighbourhood nodes, add middle one and delete 2 original nodes. I don't know how to do it for every complex path. How to contact developers of Inkscape ? Mybe there is some way for future updates.